# I want this VBA code to run from a Command Button in the current workbook

Tags: vba, import

I have a VBA (Excel 2010) code.
It imports multiple csv files and pastes them in different sheets.
But it does not import the data into the current workbook from where the code is executed. It rather opens a new workbook and does the job.

I want to be able to run this code via a Command Button and import data into the active workbook.

Any suggetions what changes I should incorporate?

Your advice is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()
    Dim FilesToOpen
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
sDelimiter = "|"
FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.csv), *.csv", _
      MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")
If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If
x = 1
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
    wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
    wkbTemp.Close (False)
    wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
    x = x + 1
While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
        Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
        With wkbAll
            wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Move After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
              TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
              ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
              Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
              Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter
        End With
        x = x + 1
    Wend
ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wkbAll = Nothing
    Set wkbTemp = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the `wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Copy` that is the problem: if you don't provde either of the optional parameters `Before` or `After`, Excel creates a copy in a new workbook (see Remarks here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837784.aspx).

You will need to set the reference to the originating workbook earlier - change your code around the opening of the first CSV as follows:

```
Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook 'moved from a few lines lower down
Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Copy After:=wkbAll.Sheets(wkbAll.Sheets.Count)
```

You will have to make the equivalent changes to the later copy methods

Comment: Hi @MarkWickett, I tried using your suggested change, but the macro exits, giving me an "Automation Error" message. It does not show where the error occurs.

Comment: Ok - not sure why you're getting that, but I did note that once you open the CSV, that becomes the ActiveWorkbook, so trying to copy that a new sheet in itself isn't going to work. I've edited my response above to reflect a more accurate solution!

Comment: Also, your error handling might be getting in the way of telling you where the error is - just comment out the `On Error Goto ErrHandler` and then you should get an option to debug at the offending statement if an error pops up. Of course, uncomment this once it's working :-)

Comment: Thanks again. But please pardon my (lack of) knowledge on VBA. I run this code with your change and now, I get an error "No data selected to parse". But I see the first file that I selected, has been imported to the ActiveWorkbook. The others are not

Answer (score 0):

I found this link helpful.

[Import multiple text files](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/importing-multiple-text-files-and-replace-contents/f13e1ca2-821c-4337-bf94-897987eaab7d)

It worked for my case, with the only exception that I'd have to select a particular folder containing all the relevant files, rather than the individual files themselves.

It would also work only for txt files because of the option **Workbooks.OpenText FileName**

Hope it also helps who face similar issues too.

Regards
asar_k